# SVG анимация path, при изменении атрибута values анимация начинается сначала

Tags: javascript, html, svg

При нажатии на блок стрелка перемещается к его правому краю. Для этого я получаю текущее значение атрибута `d` у `path` и следующее значение `d`, прибавляя координаты по X, затем обновляю значение `values` в `animate` и перезапускаю анимацию с помощью `beginElement()`.
При таком раскладе анимация работает плавно, но всегда начинается с самого первого элемента.

Если до изменения атрибута `values` остановить анимацию с помощью `endElement()` стрелка перемещается последовательно, но при этом плавный переход не работает.

В чем причина такого поведения?

```js
function getPath(item) {
  let x = item.offsetLeft + item.offsetWidth;
  return `M${x} 15 L ${40+x} 30     V20 H${60+x} V10 H${40+x} V0 Z`;
}

window.onload = function() {
  let firstItem = document.getElementById("first_item");
  document.getElementById("arrow").setAttribute("d", getPath(firstItem));

}

var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

menu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  let clickedElement = event.target;

  if (clickedElement.getAttribute("class") != "menu_item") {
    return;
  }

  let el = document.getElementById("arrow");
  let anim = el.querySelector("animate");
  let currentPath = el.getAttribute("d");

  anim.setAttribute("values", `${currentPath};${getPath(clickedElement)}`);

  anim.beginElement();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: gray;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu_item {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu" class="menu">
    <svg fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
         <path id = "arrow" d="M0 15 L 40 30    V20 H60 V10 H40 V0 Z">
            <animate attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" keySplines = "0.42 0 0.58 1" values="" fill="freeze"/>
         </path>
      </svg>
    <div id="first_item" class="menu_item">
      Item1
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      Item2
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      Item3
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      Item4
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тебе нужно менять начало анимации

```js
function getPath(item) {
  let x = item.offsetLeft + item.offsetWidth;
  return `M${x} 15 L ${40+x} 30     V20 H${60+x} V10 H${40+x} V0 Z`;
}

window.onload = function() {
  let firstItem = document.getElementById("first_item");
  document.getElementById("arrow").setAttribute("d", getPath(firstItem));

}

var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

menu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  let clickedElement = event.target;

  if (clickedElement.getAttribute("class") != "menu_item") {
    return;
  }

  let el = document.getElementById("arrow");
  let anim = el.querySelector("animate");
  let currentPath = el.getAttribute("d");

  anim.setAttribute("values", `${currentPath};${getPath(clickedElement)}`);
  el.setAttribute("d", `${getPath(clickedElement)}`);

  anim.beginElement();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: gray;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu_item {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu" class="menu">
    <svg fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
         <path id = "arrow" >
            <animate attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" keySplines = "0.42 0 0.58 1" values="" fill="freeze"/>
         </path>
      </svg>
    <div id="first_item" class="menu_item">
      Item1
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      Item2
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      Item3
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      Item4
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Действительно, обновить сам path то я и забыл...

Comment: Но почему все работает так, если добавить endElement()? Может дополните ответ?

Comment: Это работет потому что вы его перемещаете и эта функция берет стартовую актуальную точку. Но эта функция насколько я знаю не имеет анимации. **beginElement()** в свою очередь, как вы уже сказали перезапускает анимацию и для этого важно чтобы анимация была изменена